# AngularUI Bootstrap Modal. Scope issue

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Im fairly new to AngularJS and I'm trying to create an List with "Draggables" that you can drop in 4 lists which are sortable. I got this to work with AngularUI-Sortable.

Now for the next part I'm trying to edit the content (more options and settings in the feature). With a modal from AngularUI-Bootstrap.

I got this to work with opening the content from the selected item I want to edit.

As you can see in the Plunker I almost got it working. Only thing I cant figure out is how I can get the `{{ item }}` to be `{{ widgetOption }}` AFTER I pressed the save button.

http://embed.plnkr.co/TTNccRuToObZuSmwYlTG/preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach would be to keep a reference to the original object in your modal controller.  So, assume the object passed in is the original, and it should only be modified if the form is saved.  Making the fewest changes possible to your code to make it work, I came up with this plunker.

http://plnkr.co/edit/eSbEZZajsNfmVv3vmTdc?p=info

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'modal.html',
    controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
    resolve: {
        widgetOptionsLocal: function () {
            return widgetOptions;
        }
    }
});


var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, widgetOptionsLocal) {
    var widgetOptionsOriginal = widgetOptionsLocal;
    $scope.widgetOptions = angular.copy(widgetOptionsLocal);

    $scope.ok = function () {
      widgetOptionsOriginal.content = $scope.widgetOptions.content;
       $modalInstance.close($scope.widgetOptions);
    };

    $scope.cancel = function () {
       $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the example really helpful! I do have a small question, right now you do (Doing a `.content` )
`$scope.ok = function () {
      widgetOptionsOriginal.content = $scope.widgetOptions.content;
       $modalInstance.close($scope.widgetOptions);
    };`

So if I add more options too the modal I need to manually add all the options? Since the bottom code didnt work

`$scope.ok = function () {
      widgetOptionsOriginal = $scope.widgetOptions;
       $modalInstance.close($scope.widgetOptions);
    };`

Comment: With the way it's coded right now, yes.  You have to keep a reference to that original object, you can't replace it or you'll lose the association with your item list.  Two alternatives without rewriting big chunks of code:  a) use angular.extend to apply the properties of the new object to the original b) you change your code to pass in your whole list and an index, then you can replace the object in the list with the new one.

Comment: Cheers went for the angular.extend, didnt knew about that one! Thanks for the help!